# Inorder traversal of an AVL<AVL<node>>

Tags: c++, tree, avl-tree, inorder

I am trying to implement an Inorder traversal for an `AVL<AVL<..>>` (every node of the outer AVL is an AVL tree)
The traversal has to start for the minumum node (the one who has the lowest key)

I have a function to scan the outer tree :

```
void scanOuterTree(AVLTree<SongNode> *t, int* artists, int *songs, int numOfSongs, bool wentRight){  
    if (t == nullptr || artists[numOfSongs - 1] != -1){
        return;
    }

    scanInorder(t->minNode, artists, songs, numOfSongs, false);
    if(!wentRight) {
        scanOuterTree(t->parent, artists, songs, numOfSongs, false);
    }
    scanOuterTree(t->right, artists, songs, numOfSongs, true);
}
```

And another function to scan the inner tree of each outer tree:

```
void AVLTree<T>::scanInorder(SongNode* t, int* artists, int* songs, int numOfSongs, bool wentRight)
{
    if(t == nullptr || artists[numOfSongs - 1] != -1){
        return;
    }

    **do something...**  

    if(!wentRight) {
        scanInorder(t->parent, artists, songs, numOfSongs, false);
    }
    scanInorder(t->right, artists, songs, numOfSongs, true);

}
```

You can tell that this implementation is not correct because im forcing each tree to climb from the left-most node straight to the root and then go straight to the right-most node
Im quite out of ideas on how to make it work, and i would love another pair of eyes

Keep in mind that every `Node` or `AVL<node>` has the attributes `left,parent,right`

Comment: If you want to scan inorder you should first go the left, then scan the internal root tree, then go to the right. In-order traversal starts from the minimum key by definition, you don't have to write special code to make it happen.

Comment: You are right, i didnt make my pointer clear enough..
I am trying to make the traversal in O(n), meaning that i dont have to search for the left most node in O(logn) and then traverse the tree, i want to start at the left most node and start traversing in O(n), makes sense?

Comment: If you add O(logn) to O(n) then it'll still be O(n).

Comment: Imagine that the outer tree has n nodes, and each inner tree has m nodes.
Assuming that ```m << n``` so ```m << logn```  
So an inorder traversal complexity on the outer tree is logn, but i need the function to run in O(m)

Comment: Do you try to scan only the inner tree of the leftmost node of the outer tree?

Comment: Not necessarily, it should continue the scan of the outer tree as well

Comment: But if it scans the outer tree, then the complexity would still be O(n), right?

Comment: I get as a paramater ```k``` which means i have to process ```k``` nodes of the inner nodes.  
it might take 2 outer nodes to get to ```k``` inner nodes total, might take more.. 
bottom line is the complexity needs to be O(k)

Comment: I think that what you are trying to achieve is not really an in-order traversal by definition (although you want to scan the nodes in sorting order). Anyway, the internal scanning function could be `scanIn(node) :=  do_something(node); scanIn(node->right->minNode); if (node != node->parent->right) scanIn(node->parent)` and the external function could be just `scanOut(root) := scanIn(root->minNode)`.